# InvalidKeySpecException when using RSAPublicKeySpec

Tags: java, security, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key

I'm trying to instantiate a `java.security.PublicKey` by using `java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec` and `java.security.KeyFactory`.

But when running the following lines:

```
RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

I always get an exception from `org.bouncycastle` package.

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: key spec not recognised 
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source) 
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source) 
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:315)
... (25 more)
```

This confuses me since the RSAPublicKeySpec should have any relation to Bouncy Castle crypto library? Can somebody please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you instantiating the `keyFactory`?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I'm instantiating it like: `keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JDK documentation for instantiating the `KeyFactory`

> When you call the `KeyFactory.getInstance(String algorithm)`. This method
>   traverses the list of registered security Providers, starting with the
>   most preferred Provider. A new KeyFactory object encapsulating the
>   KeyFactorySpi implementation from the first Provider that supports the
>   specified algorithm is returned.

It seems like that in your environment, the `bouncy castle crypto` is the most preferred provider.

I am not aware of any default `Service Provider Interface` for `KeyFactory` in JDK. Although there are many open source implementations available, few of them are [RSAKeyFactory](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5026/libjava/gnu/java/security/provider/RSAKeyFactory.java) & [DSAKeyFactory](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5026/libjava/gnu/java/security/provider/DSAKeyFactory.java)

Hey Just found this, there are many default implementations also available in JDK. [look at this page for JCA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)